# Implement a middleware in angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Scenario:

- user opens /myapp/recovery/:token which would call a middleware which would in turn redirect the user either to 'verify' state or 'reset-pwd' state.
- these two have a screen while the recovery middleware (router/proxy/etc) won't it just redirects

How can I achieve such a functionality in angular 1.3 using ui-router?

Thanks

### Edit

This is what I did, and it seems to be working, but I'm unsure if it's the best solution.

**config.js**

```
$stateProvider.state('account-recovery', {
    url: '/account-recovery/:token',
    controller: 'AccountRecovery'
});

$stateProvider.state('verify', { ... });

$stateProvider.state('reset-pwd', { ... });
```

And in 
**account-recovery.js**

```
class AccountRecovery {

    static get $inject() {
        return ['$state' ...];
    }

    constructor($state, ...) {
        this.$state = $state;

        this.token = this.$state.params.token || '';
        this.doSomeAsync();
    }

    async doSomeAsync() {
        try {
            const response = await getSomethingFromServer();

            if (response == null || response.data == null) {
                console.error('No response');
            }

            const user = response.data;

            if (user.this) {
                this.$state.go('reset-pwd');
            }
            else if (user.that) {
                this.$state.go('verify');
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can't you just implement the logic of the state inside a controller and then, based on the results, redirect to the correct state using `$state.go()`?

Comment: Hi @AlonEitan, this is exactly what currently I am doing (still in progress) but I'm unsure if it is the possible best solution.

Comment: You should search about Http Interceptor in Angular JS you will get lot of code. That acts as a middle ware. Common place. Also what you are doing is also correct so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use the run function for the main module:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.run(runFn);

runFn.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', 'myService'];

function runFn($rootScope,$state, myService) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

      //In here you can use the $state service , i.e.
      //if(toState.name === 'account-recovery'){
      // myService.getUser().then(function(user){
      // if(user){
      //  $state.go('reset-pwd')
      // }
      // else{
      //   $state.go('verify');
      // }
      //});
    });
 }
```